# Is there a way to update a client's database without seeing all his sensitive data?

Tags: development-process

A client has asked me to update his web app. At the last minute, he has expressed some concern about allowing me access to his database (and thus to sensitive client information), because this is the first time we have worked together and he doesn't know me.

As far as I know, there is no way for me to work on this project without having full access to his database. I need to make updates to the database for one thing (adding columns, creating new tables etc). And I need to test the live app when I've updated it and I would be concerned not to have full database access.

Is there a way I can work on his project without having access to his sensitive info?

Many thanks

Comment: I imagine in an optimal situation, you create a script that can be run (even by the client) that does the updates, and you would have already tested it on dummy data.

Comment: @Tesserex: Testing on dummy data only works if the dummy data is a good representation of the real data, and even then you can get surprises!

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Could the OP ask the client for "good" dummy data? Maybe a sample of real data with redactions?

Comment: @Tesserex: Indeed, the OP could. Of course then the OP needs to ensure the test data is a good statistical sample of the whole data set, and covers all relevant test cases. That can get difficult, depending on the complexity of the data model, and would probably require a DBA.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comments. It seems to me that if the client did dummy up data, they might also create it in a way that was different to how it was originally input. Unless they wanted to fill out the forms on their app (which is where they get most of their data from) several hundred times, they might look for a different solution which could lead to them inserting data that had some differences to the form submitted data.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: And a good sample including all the inconsistencies left behind by former programmers like stray records and missing mandatory fields.

Comment: @thorsten müller: Of course! Capturing all those cases that "should never happen!", "used to happen but we fixed the app but couldn't change the key constraints", "It was a *ONE-TIME* data-fix, and shouldn't break too many records" is very important! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Options would be:

- To mask the "sensitive" data before he lets you in and then unmask it after.
- He could also move the sensitive data to a separate schema and deny you access, except maybe through a view that either masks or omits sensitive data.
- He could also delete the sensitive data and then simply reload it.
- He could give you a copy of the database with the sensitive data masked.
- He could give you the DDL to recreate the database sans data (except non-sensitive reference data) for your dev/test system.

No matter how he does it, eventually you *will* need to eventually test with data that is very similar to what is in production, or you could get nasty surprises when you implement. Masking/sanitizing results in testing on data that is not quite what the system will use in the Real World and often the differences are minor/trivial, sometimes those differences matter a lot.

Without knowing the nature of the work you're doing some of these may not be very practical or possible. And of course, if he doesn't have his own DBA, he will have to trust you do do this properly and if you're the one that sets it up, you could still see everything during the set up.

Comment: Thanks so much for your post. He doesn't have any credit card details or anything, he just seems to want to protect the names and details of his clients presumably just in case I sold the details to someone.

Comment: In the end, because he doesn't seem to have a DBA and testing and updating the live server will be therefore be difficult, I'm going to try and persuade him to give me full access.

Comment: I think these are good suggestions, but I have the nagging suspicion that the customer doesn't have the technical skills necessary for most of these options.

Answer (score 6):

If the client doesn't trust you to look at his data, how can he trust you to modify his database?

Sign a mutual NDA and get to work, or seek more trusting clients.

Comment: Happily, we've taken this option :)

Answer (score 3):

What you need to have is a testing environment.

Duplicate the schema of his database and populate it with fake data. Test against that, with your changes. Then when you're finished, you encapsulate your database changes in a single script that contains an update procedure to bring the database from the old version to the new version.

Comment: Won't work. You don't know what madness lies in the production data unless you look at it.

Comment: @Christopher Mahan: I guess you're right. I was thinking of magical unicorn land where there's a spec for what data will be stored and what it has to conform to :P

Comment: @Daenyth: Don't give up on your idea so quickly. You could dump the live data along with the schema, import it to a new db, and run a sanitizing script to replace sensitive info with fake data without losing the shape of the original data. Certainly the madness referred to by Christopher Mahan isn't the actual email address of Client number 452.

Comment: @grossvogel - good suggestion, except that I'll wager he doesn't have anyone who can write such a sanitizing script, except for the OP, who the data needs to be sanitized for! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on many factors.

Is there anybody with access to the database who could run some scripts who has enough knowledge to do this in a reliable way? For example the company which hosts his servers or his IT department?

In this case you could provide the scripts and they could run them (after doing a backup first). They could also provide you with some sample data, so you have the structure of the database but without real data in it.

This could work as long as the data is consistent and there are no errors. It becomes far more difficult if part of your work would be to clean up errors.

Comment: I don't think he does have a reliable DBA, so I would need access just to run the script. Also as you say, and other people here too, I really need to have a look at the current data to make sure my code handles all the possible formats and data. Thanks very much for your post.

Answer (score 2):

My advice: tell the customer no.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably no need to have actual data. In fact, for development purposes, you should be able to use a sanitized subset of the data. Everything should have the same characteristics as the actual data in terms of formatting, but it doesn't have to actually be the real data set.

If the data is truly sensitive in nature, integration would probably be performed in-house by technical staff. If any errors arise, they could sanitize log files and provide them to you should they need guidance.

In the event of you needing to perform the integration, it becomes much trickier. But if you have been hired to do the job, then the person paying should trust you. They should also have legal backing (NDAs and the like), but if they don't trust you to do what they hired you to do while maintaining the ethical and legal high ground, why did they hire you?

Comment: You definitely have to have a chunck of data that is the same size as the production data. updating a 500,000,000 rows table isn't the same as updating the same table with 10,000 rows.

Comment: @Christopher Not true. For performance tuning and evaluation, yes. But for developing code to work with a given schema, absolutely not. You just need enough data to account for variations in terms of content of each field. Once the software has been developed and tested against that, performance tuning can be done against a more realistic data set.

Comment: My example was poor. How do you know you need to shard unless you see the data? How do you know what changes to make to the data structure unless you know how it affects the whole?

Comment: @Christopher That's a problem at the system administration and DBA level, not for the application programmer. Any such changes should be invisible to the application. The only time you might have to worry is if you are defining your own abstraction layer. And why are you reinventing the wheel, instead of focusing on building software to solve your client's problems?

Comment: Ah, but the OP said he needs to "adding columns, creating new tables", so he's no longer in front-end-land but in DBA-land.

Comment: @Christopher Still doesn't matter. You don't need all of the data to ensure that your queries still execute and your domain objects are able to properly represent data stored in the database. Other than performance tuning (which includes sharding), you do not need any more than a small fraction of total data.

Comment: @Thomas:  Except that, when excerpting 10K rows out of 500M, you're very unlikely to hit one of those 50 that "I probably should have told you about them"/"I forgot about those"/"You mean those will be a problem?"/"The current software handles them somehow"/"Those are old, don't worry about them"/whatever.  So, everything goes great on the 10K, time to install, and it crashed 50 times a run.  It isn't tested unless it's tested on representative data, and without access to the original you have no way of knowing your test data is representative.

Comment: @David I mentioned that explicitly in my original post. "Everything should have the same characteristics as the actual data in terms of formatting, but it doesn't have to actually be the real data set." If the client won't give you real data, you need to outline exactly what you need to obtain a representative sample and have it provided to you as input. Otherwise, there's no way to ensure reliability of your product. In a case like this, without real data, your work is only as good as the sample, and that should be clearly stated so the client understands the risks and accepts them.

Comment: @Thomas:  Sure, but the only way the sample can be representative is if the person supplying it knows what he or she is doing.  You can't give exact instructions without already knowing what might be wrong with the data.  The OP seems to think the client lacks this sort of expertise.  You can write in the contract that acceptance and payment depend on tests on the sample, but a lot of clients are going to balk at that, or at least complain bitterly later.  It's a real problem with less sophisticated clients with confidential data.